# Should I attach both my bank account statements for Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas

I am planning to apply for a Tourist Schengen Visa Application (Hungary) from Azerbaijan.
I have a question regarding my bank statement.

I am self-employed, I have a registered software company, my clients are online, they pay me on Webmoney wallet.
Then Webmoney transfers the funds to me on my personal bank account (1).
After that, I transfer my funds and accumulate them to my other bank account (2).

I have Income tax papers and returns, my question is do I need to give both of the accounts statements ?

My bank account (2) is where most of my funds get accumulated and I was planning to show that statement. Would this suffice ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, You should show both of your account's statements. and describe all this situation in the Cover letter in detail.